# Difference in the following using Hive Left Outer Join

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I had an issue with the LEft outer join and my query was little bit wierd. Tried searching for it , but did not get any clues. 
This is happening due to were clause has been added.

The query below is not working as expected.

```
SELECT count(*) from 
BN_DATA_TEMP.EDS_DELIVERYITEM_GBQ_SAMPLE_DATA A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN BN_DATA_TEMP.TBL_EDS_DELIVERYITEMS_DATES B
on ( 
to_Date(substr(A.LASTUPDATEDTIME,1,10)) = '2020-05-31' 
and to_Date(substr(B.LASTUPDATEDTIME,1,10)) = '2020-05-31' 
and A.deliveryid = B.deliveryid )
where B.deliveryid is null;
```

Trying to get Records in A but not in B. But the count is very different and it is wrong.
I need to consider only the dates with 2020-05-31 from both the tables.

Modified like the below and it gave the correct result.

```
select count(*) from
(SELECT * from 
BN_DATA_TEMP.EDS_DELIVERYITEM_GBQ_SAMPLE_DATA where to_Date(substr(LASTUPDATEDTIME,1,10)) = '2020-05-31' ) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select * from 
BN_DATA_TEMP.TBL_EDS_DELIVERYITEMS_DATES where to_Date(substr(LASTUPDATEDTIME,1,10)) = '2020-05-31' ) B
on A.deliveryid = B.deliveryid
where B.deliveryid is null;
```

I have never use much of Left outer joins for Data validation. So thought of posting over here and learn the same.

Thanks in Advance.